# Weyl group action on the Lie algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems, weyl-group

Let $W$ be the Weyl group of a complex semisimple Lie algebra $\frak{g}$. Certainly $W$ acts on the root system $R$ of $\frak{g}$ but can it be made to act on $\frak{g}$ or on the universal enveloping algebra?

Comment: If you write $W = N_G(T)/T$ you see that there is no reason that $W$ should acts on $U(g)$. $W$ will usually acts on objects related to $Lie(T)$, for example center of category $\mathcal O$ with fixed character. This is related to so-called "translation functor".

Comment: There is a standard ``lift'' of $W $ to $ G $.  You can make this lift act on $ \mathfrak g $ by the adjoint action.

Comment: @JoelKamnitzer: Thanks for the comment. What is the standard lift of $W$ to $G$?

Comment: @JoelKamnitzer Unfortunately, if by $G$ you mean the Lie group, the extension of $W$ by $T$ to give $N_G(T)$ is not always split, so there isn't a "standard lift" or necessarily any lift. You can find a full discussion of this in Curtis, Wiederhold and Williams, "Normalizers of maximal tori" Springer LNM 418 (1974).

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13139/can-we-realize-weyl-group-as-a-subgroup

Comment: @Bugs Bunny: Yes, I think this does answer my question. Thanks a lot!